# Error occur when I write name in application of manifest file. I make the same class as my project name. I'm using android 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-layout, manifest

The name AChat of my application. When I write name in application the error come.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".AChat"
    >
```

Comment: What is the *error* then ? Remove *.* sign just keep it as *AChat*.

Comment: I remove . sign but error still come

Comment: What is the error then ? Show here.

Comment: do not show any message just " class or interface  is expected"

Comment: check for your packageName in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need a create a class that extends **Application** and has name **AChat**. Try this and your error will be gone.

Comment: is there any way to send screen shot. I send it to you.

Comment: Do one thing, delete that class. Once deleted, remove the dot from AChat and then press Alt + Enter while the cursor is on AChat and click on create Class.

Comment: I delete the class and press many time Alt+Enter. is does not show any message to create class

Comment: Was your cursor on AChat?

Comment: yes it was on the AChat and other three option show 1-edit java fragment  2- language injection 3-uninjection language